# Android App Push Data to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: android, export, google-sheets

I'm developing an Android-based scorekeeping application for the card game "Spades".

Currently I am saving the results of each hand to a "Hand History" tab in text format.

I am wondering how I could export this and other simple information to a google spreadsheet.  This API seems like a lot to sift through:  http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/

It appears it can be easier if I publish my google spreadsheet and don't require a login to access it.

Much appreciated,
K.H.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have seen this code for google spreadsheet api http://www.farinspace.com/saving-form-data-to-google-spreadsheets/ which is in PHP. From that code snippet, it looks easier to push the data.